# Trying to pass parameter in android

Tags: java, android, function, parameter-passing

So I have two files (`MainActivity.java` and `HomeFragment.java`) and I am trying to pass a `public static void` called `displayPromptForEnablingGPS` from `HomeFragment` to `MainActivity`. Here is the code

`HomeFragment.java` (the code I'm trying to pass)

```
public static void displayPromptForEnablingGPS(
        final Activity activity)
{
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder =
            new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    final String action = Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS;
    final String message = "Enable either GPS or any other location"
            + " service to find current location.  Click OK to go to"
            + " location services settings to let you do so.";


    builder.setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int id) {
                            activity.startActivity(new Intent(action));
                            d.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int id) {
                            d.cancel();
                        }
                    });
    builder.create().show();
}
```

`MainActivity.java` (how I'm trying to call it)

```
public void showMainView() {
   HomeFragment.displayPromptForEnablingGPS();
}
```

But I get an error saying

`"HomeFragment.displayPromptForEnablingGPS();" is invalid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you want to call requires a parameter but you don't pass it.

```
public static void displayPromptForEnablingGPS(
    final Activity activity)
```

Your method in MainActivity should look like this:

```
public void showMainView() {
   HomeFragment.displayPromptForEnablingGPS(this);
}
```